# How does this line from a Bash Script work?

Tags: bash, syntax

I'm trying to figure out how a certain line of code from the top of [BASH man page tab completion script](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/52315ef2ceb3f8e6b7fe45a09f8df24b73394da4/completions/man#L3) works:

```
[[ $OSTYPE == *@(darwin|freebsd|solaris|cygwin|openbsd)* ]] || _userland GNU \
    || return 1
```

I believe it's a guard; if the BASH special variable `$OSTYPE` does not contain one of the strings in the (basic regular?) expression contained within parentheses, or if the userland is GNU then it'll discontinue execution of the script. But, I can't understand how the syntax works or what it means and I don't know what the flow of control is.

You can find the definition of `_userland` [here](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/52315ef2ceb3f8e6b7fe45a09f8df24b73394da4/bash_completion#L97):

```
# Check if we're running on the given userland
# @param $1 userland to check for
_userland()
{
    local userland=$( uname -s )
    [[ $userland == @(Linux|GNU/*) ]] && userland=GNU
    [[ $userland == $1 ]]
}
```

How does this function work? Does it return a value?

If you could provide references to relevant documentation or articles, that would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a chain of `c1 || c2 || c3 || ...` each command will be tried until one is successful. After a successful command, the remaining commands in the chain will not be executed.

So in this chain of commands:

```
[[ $OSTYPE == *@(darwin|freebsd|solaris|cygwin|openbsd)* ]] \
|| _userland GNU \
|| return 1
```

If `OSTYPE` is one of darwin, freebsd, etc, then the chain stops. You can read more about the pattern used there in `man bash`, search for **Pattern Matching**. In this example, the rule that applies is:

> ```
> @(pattern-list)
>     Matches one of the given patterns
> ```

The patterns are separated by `|`. The `*` around the `@(...)` means that these patterns can occur anywhere within `OSTYPE`. Only `@(...)` would mean exact match on the given patterns, `@(...)*` would mean starting with any of the given patterns, `*@(...)` would mean ending with the any of the given patterns.

If `OSTYPE` didn't match, we try the next item in the chain: `_userland GNU`. If successful, then the chain stops. Otherwise we try the next item in the chain, which is `return 1`, so we exit the function.

The `_userland` function does:

- `local userland=$( uname -s )` : store the output of `uname -s` command in a local variable called `userland`
- `[[ $userland == @(Linux|GNU/*) ]] && userland=GNU` : if the value is `Linux` or starts with `GNU/`, then set `userland=GNU`
- `[[ $userland == $1 ]]` : compare the value to the parameter we received. The exit code of this comparison is the return value of the function. If the value matches, that means success.

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me!

Comment: Just for completeness sake: On my Mac OS, when I run `echo $OSTYPE` I get the output `darwin15`. And the **Pattern Matching** section of bash's man page says if the `extglob` `shopt` option is set (it is, in the `bash_completion` script, the same one that defines `_userland`), then `*(pattern-list)` "[m]atches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns" where "a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated by a `|`". This looks like a full solution to me!

Comment: Hmm, actually I don't quite understand the pattern matching, I don't get the trailing `*` (is that just "Matches any string, including the null string"? does that serve any purpose?) or why they don't use a `+` to precede the open paren. I thought that'd mean that it had to include one of the patterns in the list.

Comment: I added more explanation about the pattern, see my updated post.